# MacBook Pro crashes when two external monitors plugged in

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake, crash

When I plug in two external 4K monitors into the Thunderbolt ports, my MacBook Pro 2019 frequently crashes. There is no crash report visible.

This can also happen when trying to wake from sleep while the two monitors are connected.

This used to happen with my MacBook Pro 2017 so I bought a 2019 with the highest possible specs on the graphics card only to find it has exactly the same issue.

Is there any solution to prevent this?

Comment: Manufacturer and model(s) of 4K monitors would be helpful. Have you tried other cables?

Comment: Not sure of the model because I can't find it on the monitor, but they are LG's. I'm testing with new cables to see if that was the issue.